# Array to Object es6 javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am trying to see if there is a smaller way of converting an array to an object in es6. **( I do not have to worry about cross-browser )**

I currently have:

```
function (values) // values being an array.
{   
    let [videos, video_count, page] = values;
    let data = { videos, video_count, page };
    someFunctions(data);
    moreFunctions(data);
}
```

But I was wondering if it's possible to cut out the first line of the function, `let [videos....]` part. And somehow **inline** do the conversion.

I have read through [mozilla: Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) but I could not see it there. *(but I may have understood it wrong)* and I am really not clever enough to understand [ECMA: ES6 Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-assignment).

I suspect it is not possible and the above is already the simplest I can make it.
But if I can get away with not creating the `videos`, `video_count` & `page` tmp variables I would be happier.

Comment: Could always do it the old-fashioned way: `var data = {videos:values[0], video_count:values[1], page:values[2]};`

Comment: It was something I had considered, but wanted to see if there was a es6 way. There seemed to be a way to do almost all of what I wanted, I guess I found a more niche use case.

Comment: Well, either way you have to name your property values, they won't come out of nowhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can destructure right in the function parameters

```
function myFunc([ videos, video_count, page ])
{   
    let data = { videos, video_count, page };
    someFunctions(data);
    moreFunctions(data);
}

myFunc(values);
```

I do a lot of data abstraction using this technique

```js
// basic abstraction
const ratio = (n, d) => ({n, d});
const numer = ({n}) => n;
const denom = ({d}) => d;

// compound abstraction using selectors
const ratioAdd = (x,y) => ratio(
  numer(x) * denom(y) + numer(y) * denom(x),
  denom(x) * denom(y)
);

// or skip selectors if you're feeling lazy
const printRatio = ({n,d}) => `${n}/${d}`;

console.log(printRatio(ratioAdd(ratio(1,3), ratio(1,4)))); //= 7/12
```

---

You seem hell-bent on somehow making the code shorter, so here you go. In this case, *"making it shorter"* means making it longer first.

```
// Goal:
obuild(keys,values) //=> ourObject
```

Generic procedures `zip`, `assign`, and `obuild` should give us what we need. This is vastly superior to @CodingIntigue's answer as it's not one big function that tries to do all of the tasks. Keeping them separate means reducing complexity, and increasing readability and reusability.

```js
// zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [[a,b]]
const zip = ([x,...xs], [y,...ys]) => {
  if (x === undefined || y === undefined)
    return [];
  else
    return [[x,y], ...zip(xs,ys)];
}

// assign :: (Object{k:v}, [k,v]) -> Object{k:v}
const assign = (o, [k,v]) => Object.assign(o, {[k]: v});

// obuild :: ([k], [v]) -> Object{k:v}
const obuild = (keys, values) => zip(keys, values).reduce(assign, {});

let keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let values = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(obuild(keys,values));
// { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
```

Comment: This still ends up with tmp variables? Though `values` is now gone, the three I was mainly trying to remove still exist.

Comment: *This is vastly superior to @CodingIntigue's answer* - Ouch. You're not wrong though, much more readable.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue I truly mean no harm by it; I'm in the middle of a really annoying task and otherwise probably would've worded that more tactfully.

Comment: @naomik No offence taken, it's not an incorrect statement!

Comment: @naomik FYI, I went with your destructuring within the function arguments in the end. It looked the neatest so far. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

With the given properties and names you have, that's probably the shortest way to achieve your desired result.

However, if you had more fields, you could use `reduce` to avoid repetition. It's not as readable as the destructuring though:

```
let data = values.reduce((prev, val, index) => Object.assign(prev, {[["videos", "video_count", "page"][index]]: val} ), {});
```

You could then abstract that out into a generic function:

```js
const values = ["test1","test2","test3"];
const mapArrayToObject = (array, fields) =>
  array.reduce(
    (prev, val, index) => Object.assign(prev, { [fields[index]]: val } ),
    {}
  );
const data = mapArrayToObject(values, ["videos", "video_count", "page"]);
console.log(data);
```